# Bluemix - Use Insights for Twitter API to query if a topic is trendy

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm implementing a sorting algorithm and I want to query the **Insights for Twitter API** in order to find if a topic is trendy in comparison to another topic.

As far as I've investigated, there is a **Count** API Operation which will return the number of Tweets based on a given query. Therefore I could query how many Tweets have the particular "keyword" in their body and then compare it to other different keywords to establish an order.

Is there is a more direct query to know if a keyword is trendy?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using the ***/api/v1/messages/count*** endpoint looks like the right one when working with the Insights for Twitter API.

I guess you could also use the *posted* query parameter to build trending charts over time for your different keywords.